# Can not get a hit in XML using XPath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://.../nuget/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Packages</title>
  <id>http://.../nuget/Packages</id>
  <updated>2019-06-24T08:30:28Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Packages" href="Packages" />
<id>http://.../nuget/Packages(Id='7zip',Version='16.0.2')</id>
    <title type="text">programma</title>
    <summary type="text">Programma is a file archiver with a high compression ratio.</summary>
    <updated>2018-06-19T15:33:22Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Herman</name>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit-media" title="ODataPackage" href="Packages(Id='7zip',Version='16.0.2')/$value" />
    <link rel="edit" title="ODataPackage" href="Packages(Id='7zip',Version='16.0.2')" />
    <category term="NuGet.Server.DataServices.ODataPackage"scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/zip" src="http://.../api/v2/package/7zip/16.0.2" />
    <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
      <d:Version>16.0.2</d:Version>
      <d:NormalizedVersion>16.0.2</d:NormalizedVersion>
      <d:IsPrerelease m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsPrerelease>
      <d:Title>7-Zip</d:Title>
      <d:Owners>Herman</d:Owners>
      <d:IconUrl m:null="true"></d:IconUrl>
      <d:LicenseUrl>http://www.7-zip.org/license.txt</d:LicenseUrl>
      <d:ProjectUrl>http://www.7-zip.org/</d:ProjectUrl>
      <d:DownloadCount m:type="Edm.Int32">-1</d:DownloadCount>
      <d:RequireLicenseAcceptance m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:RequireLicenseAcceptance>
      <d:DevelopmentDependency m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:DevelopmentDependency>
      <d:Description>7-Zip is a file archiver with a high compression ratio.
```

Using Xpath, the following code in Powershell gives some values for $entry:

```
$xpath = "//atom:title[contains(text(),'$ChocoPackageName')]"
$entry = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath $xpath -Namespace @{atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
$entry | Should Not BeNullOrEmpty
```

Now I have to create a xpath to find the node with specific Version (16.0.2) in Version in properties

I produced:

```
$xpath = "//Version[contains(text(), '$Version')]"
$entry = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath $xpath -Namespace @{atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
$entry | Should Not BeNullOrEmpty
```

I cannot get it to work. Whatever I trie in defining XPath. How can I define a $xpath to feed/entry/properties/Version

Please help!

Comment: Well, this is not the complete XML file, thus leaving out stuff you are asking for. I get you need to sanitize it, but not supplying all the info just leaves us to guess at what is really there / thus what is going on, thus make recommendations. Lastly, when going after version information, consider using the .Net [version] namespace.

Comment: I just need a xpath to get to m: properties/d:Version. The whole xml is 8 pages long... I have to find nodes with $version being a string "16.0.2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Version` element is in a **different namespace** that you did not declare in your PS script:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
...
<d:Version>16.0.2</d:Version>
```

Similar to the code you said is already working:

```
$xpath = "//d:Version[contains(text(), '$Version')]"
$entry = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath $xpath -Namespace @{d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"}
```

Disclaimer: I am not a Powershell expert, so I cannot say whether this is an optimal solution in PS.